# Extracting only the polygons from a shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am using [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) to load a shapefile and extract the boundaries from the Valencia city in Spain. I execute my query using the QuickOSM plugin and I want only the polygons within the Valencia city. However, the QuickOSM plugin does not show this option to me.

I need the polygons in order to find a point inside the neighborhoods of Valencia. How can I extract only the polygons from a shapefile using QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Advanced uncheck Points, Lines, and Multilinestrings.

EDIT:

To convert the resulting multipolygon to single polygons open the Processing Toolbox, navigate to Vector Geometry > Multipart to singleparts, select the multipolygon as the input layer and choose a place to save the result. The result will be singlepart polygons.

Comment: by doing that I only extract a file with `MultiPolygon`, which I am already doing. I want a file with `Polygon`.

Comment: See my edit above.